# How to build a tree node with Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular

I have to generate a tree node with Angular. The object is called Page and each Page can have children and those children can also have their own children and so on.

Now I have to show the hierarchical structure in HTML from my Angular Page object.

Also, what I would want to indent the children like this:

- Page parent #1
- .... Child page of #1
- ......... Child of child page #1
- Page parent #2
- .... Child page of #2
- ........ Child of child page #2

You get the idea.

My page object is:

```
export class PageModel {
  id!: number;
  title?: string | undefined;
  typeId?: string | undefined;
  parentId?: number | undefined;
  children?: PageModel[] | undefined;
  publishedDateLocal?: string | undefined;
}
```

My html component is for now a simple table...

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Page Type</td>
      <td>Published</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let page of model.pageModels">
      <td>{{ page?.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ page?.pageTypeId }}</td>
      <td>{{ page?.publishedDateLocal }}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="remove" (click)="deletePage(page.id)" [routerLink]="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/pageAddEdit', page.id]">
            Edit
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: How to build the hierarchical structure with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a recursive structure for this.

Create a very simply component that takes `PageModel` as an input. You can then display that, and look through each of the children using `*ngFor`, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <li>{{model.title}}</li>
  <ul>
      <hello *ngFor="let child of model.children" [model]="child"></hello>
  </ul>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() model: PageModel;

}
```

Here is a simple 
[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovai5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)